# Getting text from td cells with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in jQuery:

```
children('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td')
```

Which gets all table cells for each row. My question is: how can I get the text value in each cell in each row?

Should I use `.each()` to loop trough all `children('td')`? How can I get the text value of each `td`?

Comment: What do you want to do with this text value? How do you want it formatted? Please explain your situation with more detail.

Comment: I will use it as a plain text. Also some of the fields are needed as numbers/dates/time, for example i need time started.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

First of all, your selector is overkill. I suggest using a class or ID selector like my example below. Once you've corrected your selector, simply use jQuery's [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through the collection:

**ID Selector:**

```
$('#mytable td').each(function() {
    var cellText = $(this).html();    
});
```

**Class Selector:**

```
$('.myTableClass td').each(function() {
    var cellText = $(this).html();    
});
```

**Additional Information:**

Take a look at [jQuery's selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 16):

You can use `.map`: http://jsfiddle.net/9ndcL/1/.

```
// array of text of each td

var texts = $("td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I would give your tds a specific class, e.g. *data-cell*, and then use something like this:

```
$("td.data-cell").each(function () {
    // 'this' is now the raw td DOM element
    var txt = $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').on('click', function() {
    var value = $this.text();
  });
});
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".field-group_name").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
```